# Does a java web application need a 'server' side part to add markers into Google maps

Tags: java, google-maps

I am developing a small web application in java. My intention is to select all logged in players displaying in the List Players screen and add to Google Maps by clicking on some button. 
I have already completed the 'client side' coding in java script for adding of players markers, finding their geo-location and displaying in Google Maps.
So my question here is, do I need to develop a 'server side' program in java for adding markers and geolocation ? or will the client side javascript code is sufficient to see all logged in players on map. Could someone please clarify ?

**Technology used:** Java, jsp, servlets, Apache tomcat, jstl, Google Maps API and My SQL.

On click on a button calls a selectPlayer() javascript function and pass two arrays 'arr1, arr2 ' as arguments in LocateMe(labels, newimages).js function which will add a marker in Google map.

```
function locateMe(labels, newimages) {
newcords = getLocation();
for (i=0; i< labels.length; i++ ){
    var temLabel = labels[i].innerText;     
    plyrImages =  newimages[0].src ;


        userMarker[i] = new google.maps.Marker({
            position : { lat : currentLatitude, lng : currentLongitude},
            zoom : 9,
            icon : 'images/pointer1.PNG',
            title : temLabel,
            draggable : true,
            map : map

        });

        markers.push(userMarker[i]);        
        makeAjaxCall(currentLatitude, currentLongitude, temLabel, plyrEmail); 
        window.setInterval(changeMarkerPosition(userMarker[i]), 3000);

    }

}
```

Once the marker is added, invoke an ajax call called 'makeAjaxCall() which will call a 'playerLocation' servlet push lat,long, name details into database.
My problem here is after saving the location data into database, I would like to call function 'window.setInterval(changeMarkerPosition(userMarker[i]), 3000)' 
I am sending a json response back as below;

```
String json = new Gson().toJson(data);          
             response.setContentType("application/json");
             response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
             response.getWriter().write(json);
             RequestDispatcher rd = request
                    .getRequestDispatcher("listplayers.jsp");
             rd.forward(request, response);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to store the location of the users somewhere. A good place for that purpose would be a database on the server. The server's application must be able to load that data and send it to the client-side, preferably in JSON. The client-side would then take that JSON data and generate the markers.

You will not always need server-side logic to generate markers. If you have a reliable data-source for some reason, then you will not need to make another. However, since this is about the positions of your users, which can be changed, you will need the server-side.

Comment: Much appreciated for your reply Lajos. For saving location of each user into a database can I call servlets to do that ? A different table to store user's location. But how will i use json to load server data and send back to front end? Any pointers?

Comment: You can use an AJAX request to send the location to the server. You will need a table to be able to store the user's location. You can convert something to JSON in Java in many ways, for example: https://www.mkyong.com/java/jackson-2-convert-java-object-to-from-json/. In our case you will need a JSON string and generate that into the page as a value of a Javascript variable.

Comment: I will try that

Comment: I have a 'getLocation()' function which returns me, 'currentLatitude and currentLongitude'

 I have passed this 'currentLatitude and currentLongitude' in ajax function as below;

Comment: `makeAjaxCall(currentLatitude, currentLongitude);`

I have given the local server url in the Url part of the ajax function and trying to alert the 'currentLatitude, currentLongitude'

`function makeAjaxCall (currentLatitude, currentLongitude) {
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "http:localhost:8081/MyFirstJavaTest/",
    data: "",
    success: function(data){
            //return the variable here
            alert(currentLatitude, currentLongitude);
    }
  });
}`

Comment: Lajos Arpad .. Is the above seem to be ok ?

Comment: @soccerway you need to send your data to the server with the AJAX request: function makeAjaxCall (currentLatitude, currentLongitude) { $.ajax({ type: "POST", url: "http:localhost:8081/MyFirstJavaTest/", data: {currentLatitude: currentLatitude, currentLongitude: currentLongitude}, success: function(data){ //return the variable here alert(currentLatitude, currentLongitude); } }); } and you will need to use those POST parameters at your server.

Comment: I have successfully save the lat,  long details into database via Ajax. But i got 'changeMarker()' function which update the marker position on map when location change is  not happening now. How can we call that js function once after saving into database and along with the response forward operation from servlet

Comment: @soccerway I do not know enough details about your project to determine how to get rid of unnecessary calls to changeMarker in your case. However, once you save the data into the database, you could include the necessary changes into the JSON response. The client-side would take the JSON and would issue changeMarker for each needed case.

Comment: Thanks Again, I have added the code above, here lat, long and title will send as Json response back to Jsp. If I need to call the window.setInterval(changeMarkerPosition(userMarker[i]), 3000);
Do i need add a new ajax again with type "GET" and call this function  'window.setInterval(changeMarkerPosition(userMarker[i]), 3000);'  ? Will it work ?

Comment: @soccerway I think your idea is good, but it is implemented upside down. We need to have a function which gathers data, sends it to the server via AJAX and refreshes the positions in the callback. This function should be invoked inside a setInterval, to make sure it is being executed infinitely many times. Instead, you have the setInterval called inside the function, which will call changeMarkerPosition every 3 seconds and reuse the results of a single AJAX call. changeMarkerPosition should be executed in the AJAX request's callback. I think you are very close to the solution.